# Removing element by class name with HTMLAgilityPack c#

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using the html agility pack to read the contents of my html document into a string etc. After this is done, I would like to remove certian elements in that content by their class, however I am stumbling upon a problem.

My Html looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="maincolumn" >
        <div class="breadCrumbContainer">
            <div class="breadCrumbs">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="seo_list">
            <div class="seo_head">Header</div>
        </div>

Content goes here...
</div>
```

Now, I have used an xpath selector to get all the content within the  and used the InnerHtml property like so:

```
            node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='wrapper']");
            if (node != null)
            {
                pageContent = node.InnerHtml;
            }
```

From this point, I would like to remove the div with the class of "breadCrumbContainer", however when using the code below, I get the error: "Node "" was not found in the collection"

```
            node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='wrapper']");
            node = node.RemoveChild(node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='breadCrumbContainer']"));

            if (node != null)
            {
                pageContent = node.InnerHtml;
            }
```

Can anyone shed some light on this please? I'm quite new to Xpath, and really new to the HtmlAgility library.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: is it because the 'breadCrumbContainer' node isn't a direct child of 'wrapper', and .RemoveChild() may only remove direct children?

Comment: I don't know if HtmlAgilityPack works the same, but in XPath a `"//div"` will always search from the root, not from the node. Try using `".//div"` instead.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, very short and easy XSLT solution. :).  Remember: XSLT is the language designed for exactly such tasks and any other language is inferior to it for these tasks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because RemoveChild can only remove a direct child, not a grand child. Try this instead:

```
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='breadCrumbContainer']");
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Comment: Yep. How silly of me. I had expected it to count any nodes underneath as a child node. Anyways, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a super-simple task for XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "div[@class='breadCrumbContainer'
     and
       ancestor::div[@id='wrapper']
      ]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (with added another `<div>` and wrapped into an `<html>` top element to make it more challenging and realistic):

```
<html>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="maincolumn" >
        <div class="breadCrumbContainer">
            <div class="breadCrumbs"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="seo_list">
            <div class="seo_head">Header</div>
        </div>  Content goes here...
    </div>
 </div>
 <div>
   Something else here
 </div>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="maincolumn">
      <div class="seo_list">
        <div class="seo_head">Header</div>
      </div>  Content goes here...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   Something else here
 </div>
</html>
```